# PHP - Compare two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

These are my 2 arrays:

```
Array
(
[25] => Array
    (
        [items_to_give] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [xx] => xx
                        [xx] => xx
                    )

            )

        [items_to_get] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [xx] => xx
                        [xx] => xx
                    )

            )

    )

[26] => Array
    (
        [items_to_give] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [xx] => xx
                        [xx] => xx
                    )

            )

        [items_to_get] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [xx] => xx
                        [xx] => xx
                    )

            )

    )

[36] => Array
    (
        [items_to_give] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [xx] => xx
                        [xx] => xx
                    )
            )

        [items_to_get] => Array
            (
               [0] => Array
                    (
                        [xx] => xx
                        [xx] => xx
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

**and**

```
Array
(
[25] => Array
    (
        [items_to_give] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [xx] => xx
                        [xx] => xx
                    )

            )

        [items_to_get] => Array
            (
                 [0] => Array
                    (
                        [xx] => xx
                        [xx] => xx
                    )

            )

    )

[26] => Array
    (
        [items_to_give] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [xx] => xx
                        [xx] => xx
                    )

            )

        [items_to_get] => Array
            (
                 [0] => Array
                    (
                        [xx] => xx
                        [xx] => xx
                    )

            )

    )

[30] => Array
    (
        [items_to_give] => Array
            (
                 [0] => Array
                    (
                        [xx] => xx
                        [xx] => xx
                    )

            )

        [items_to_get] => Array
            (
                 [0] => Array
                    (
                        [xx] => xx
                        [xx] => xx
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

And now i want to compare these arrays and return all arrayitems which are contained in both arrays. In the example these are [25] and [26].

So the returned array should look like this (As i said [25] and [26] are contained in both arrays so its returned):

```
Array
(
[25] => Array
    (
        [items_to_give] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [xx] => xx
                        [xx] => xx
                    )

            )

        [items_to_get] => Array
            (
                 [0] => Array
                    (
                        [xx] => xx
                        [xx] => xx
                    )

            )

    )

[26] => Array
    (
        [items_to_give] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [xx] => xx
                        [xx] => xx
                    )

            )

        [items_to_get] => Array
            (
                 [0] => Array
                    (
                        [xx] => xx
                        [xx] => xx
                    )

            )

    )
)
```

**What i already tried:**

```
$result = array_map("unserialize", array_intersect($this->serialize_array_values($array1),$this->serialize_array_values($array2)));

function serialize_array_values($arr){
    foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
        sort($val);
        $arr[$key]=serialize($val);
    }

    return $arr;
}
```

But this returns the array in the wrong format. The [items_to_give] and [items_to_get] are getting converted to the index [0] and [1] which is undesirable.

I want the array to **stay as he is** when returned that means i need [items_to_give] and [items_to_get] instead of indexes [0] and [1]

What are other possible solutions? Thanks for solutions.

Comment: array_intersect()  and array_intersect_assoc()

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [array_intersect_key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php)

Comment: Semi-offtopic: your sample code modifies an array it is traversing. This may lead to undefined and unpredictable behaviour. If you need to modify an array's contents while walking, use references, ie. `foreach($arr as $key => &$val) { $val++; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function:

```
function my_array_diff($arr1, $arr2)
  {
    $res = array();
    foreach ($arr1 as $val1) {
      $val1 = serialize($val1);
      foreach ($arr2 as $key2 => $val2) {
        if (serialize($val2) == $val1) {
          $res[$key2] = $val2;
        }
      }
    }

    return $res;
  }
```